# CSS Media queries and positioning elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do 2 things.

1. get the elements with id chicken, beef and sushi to stick to the upper right side of their parent element.
2. Make the page responsive depending on the screen size without using external frameworks like bootstrap or anything else. I'm trying to use media queries but I the page still does not change to match the matching images.

Thank you.

Layouts illustration for the different screen sizes:

[desktop](http://www.z1labs.com/imgs/desktop.png)

[tablet](http://www.z1labs.com/imgs/tablet.png)

[mobile](http://www.z1labs.com/imgs/mobile.png)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

p {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

hr {
  border: solid 3px;
  black;
}

#chicken {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ff6666;
  display: block;
  color: black;
}

#beef {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: darkred;
  display: block;
  color: white;
}

#sushi {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #e6ac00;
  display: block;
  color: black;
}


/*Simple Responsive Framework.*/

.row {
  width: 100%;
}


/********** Desktop devices **********/

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-1,
  .col-lg-2,
  .col-lg-3,
  .col-lg-4,
  .col-lg-5,
  .col-lg-6,
  .col-lg-7,
  .col-lg-8,
  .col-lg-9,
  .col-lg-10,
  .col-lg-11,
  .col-lg-12 {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 20px;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}


/********** Tablet devices *********/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .col-md-1,
  .col-md-2,
  .col-md-3,
  .col-md-4,
  .col-md-5,
  .col-md-6,
  .col-md-7,
  .col-md-8,
  .col-md-9,
  .col-md-10,
  .col-md-11,
  .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 20px;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/********* Mobile devices *********/

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-sm-1,
  .col-sm-2,
  .col-sm-3,
  .col-sm-4,
  .col-sm-5,
  .col-sm-6,
  .col-sm-7,
  .col-sm-8,
  .col-sm-9,
  .col-sm-10,
  .col-sm-11,
  .col-sm-12 {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 20px;
  }
  .col-sm-1 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-3 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Our Menu</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
    <p id="chicken">Chicken</p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
    <p id="beef">Beef</p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
    <p id="sushi">Sushi</p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to me you don't want floats. Wrap the ID's in spans and text align them right.

Answer (score 0):

you are using margin to container divs, which has a width in percentage. for example for desktop, it's 33.33%. usually, for responsive try to avoid margin to parent containers and use padding or some other trick to achieve the design. I have fixed the code for desktop and mobile. the tablet is pretty straightforward. `

```css
   * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

p {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

hr {
    border: solid 3px black;
}
#chicken {
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ff6666;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    margin: 0;
}

#beef {
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: darkred;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
}

#sushi {
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #e6ac00;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    margin: 0;
}
.chickenContainer, .beefContainer, .sushiContainer{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: gray;
} 

/*Simple Responsive Framework.*/
.row {
    width: 100%;
}

/********** Desktop devices **********/
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6,
    .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
        float: left;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    .col-lg-1 {
        width: 33.33%;
    }
    .col-lg-2 {
        width: 33.33%;
    }
    .col-lg-3 {
        width: 33.33%;
    }

}

/********** Tablet devices *********/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6,
    .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
        float: left;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    .col-md-1 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .col-md-2 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .col-md-3 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/********* Mobile devices *********/
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6,
    .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12 {
        float: left;      
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    .col-sm-1 {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .col-sm-2 {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .col-sm-3 {
        width: 100%;
    }

}
```

```html
 <h1>Our Menu</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
          <div class="chickenContainer">
            <p id="chicken">Chicken</p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                <div class="beefContainer">
            <p id="beef">Beef</p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                <div class="sushiContainer">
            <p id="sushi">Sushi</p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

`